# Using Resources to store data in json file in Angular

Tags: angularjs

Folks I have a form on my website who's data I want to store in a json file.

Here is the code for the form:

```
 <form>
    <input ng-model="obj.firstname">
    <input ng-model="obj.lastname">     
    <button ng-click="storedata()">Click here to store data</button>        
</form>
```

My Angular code is as below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap.dialog','ngResource']);

myApp.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope,$dialog,TestResource) { 
 $scope.obj = {};
 $scope.obj.firstname = "Mahatma";
 $scope.obj.lastname = "Gandhi";

 $scope.storedata = function() {
    console.log("Storing Data now");
    TestResource.save($scope.obj);
    console.log("Data should have been stored");
 }
});


myApp.factory('TestResource', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('test.json', {}, {} );
}]);
```

The problem is that the data does not get stored. Am I missing something here ? 
Here is a plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3662702

Comment: What does store mean? Storing on server? Did you mean request is going?

Comment: nopes..just storing in a file.. I have a file  in the same folder called test.json

Comment: AngularJS or as a matter of fact, javascript can only send data to server, saving logic should be on server.

Comment: Did you mean save a file locally, as in, forcing a text file download through the browser? because that would help me out with something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ngResource is an Angular service designed to interact with RESTful server side data sources (see [ngResource docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)). The angular js tutorials tend to reference local JSON files since they're meant to be stand-alone examples which anyone can download and run locally without the need for a back-end server. But you'll notice the tutorials only read data from the JSON files, they cannot update them.

If you're looking to save data client side, check out LocalStorage (http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

If you're trying to save the data server side, you'll need to setup some back end service (via NodeJS, PHP, .NET, Ruby, Python, and many other frameworks..)